# Trouble when executing the same ffmpeg command for many times

Tags: ffmpeg

## Description

when using the same ffmpeg command for a couple of times, some of those will succeed, but, some of those would failed, ffmpeg report `Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height` or `Invalid data found when processing input` error.

## Input

***ffprobe***

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/2137b8d42dcf4607a625755994133e69':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
  Duration: 00:01:00.02, start: 0.021333, bitrate: N/A
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 60.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x798 [SAR 1:1 DAR 320:133], 3255 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

## Command

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /tmp/2137b8d42dcf4607a625755994133e69 -f mp4 -b:v 3000k -r 24.0 -map_metadata -1 -vf scale=50:50 -y /tmp/foo.mp4
```

## Detail

when I execute same command above 10 times, error would occur like 3 - 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the reason, it's kind of complicated to explain, it's just a problem of mine, not ffmpeg.